# Checkout windows style line breaks

Tags: libgit2sharp

Does libgit2sharp support checking out windows style line breaks when the repo has unix style line breaks?

I can't seem to find that documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does libgit2sharp support checking out windows style line breaks when the repo has unix style line breaks?

Yes. LibGit2Sharp will glady honor `core.crlf` configuration settings and `.gitattributes` files on Windows.

There are still some cases (`core.crlf` = `true` on *nix platforms, handling of `safe.crlf`) that aren't supported yet, but should be tackled shortly (cf. **[#961](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/961)**, **[libgit2/#3199](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/3199)** and **[libgit2/#2798](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/2798)**)

Comment: Did that answer provide you with any help?

Comment: I suppose you mean core.autocrlf?

Comment: I'm on https://www.nuget.org/packages/LibGit2Sharp/0.21.0.176 and it doesn't seem to work. My systemwide settings has this:
[core]
 symlinks = false
 autocrlf = true

No global or local file setting autocrlf to anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @BjarteSkogøy That's unexpected. Can you please update your question with a short but complete example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Thinking helps ... Maybe I know why. I've cloned the repository with TortoiseGit to a share. Another machine with no git related installations is using libgit2sharp to update the repo on the same share, but that machine doesn't have any autocrlf settings anywhere. Can I somehow specify the default behavior of libgit2sharp?

Comment: You can temporarily (or not ;-) ) modify, with LibGit2Sharp, the local repository configuration settings to set `config.autocrlf` to `true`, before the `Checkout()` invokation. Something like `repo.Config.Set("core.autocrlf", true);` should work.